# Why have objects moved from their original positions when I reopen my Blender file and how do I fix it?

Tags: objects

I was working on a skull model yesterday and had aligned all of the bones. Today, when I opened the Blender file, the bones were scattered - seemingly randomly rotated and translated.

I think the issue may have been caused because I received this file from a collaborator, who had keyframed some things to create a spinning animation. I wasn't aware of this and just worked on the scene and did not keyframe anything. I also tried deleting the keyframes and also unparenting bones and keeping transforms but nothing worked.

Does anyone know if there is any way to recover the overall scene?

Answer (score 2):

If the objects were keyframed and then moved without setting keyframes once more, the information was not saved with the file and is lost.

You should manually realign the objects this time and in the future if you have animated objects in a similar situation where you don't want the animation, you should select them all, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for Remove Animation function:

[image]

Comment: Oh no, that is a shame that they cannot be recovered. Thank you for the advice on how to set up the scenes in the future

Answer (score 0):

If you set up autosave, you can try to recover one of the autosaves from the previous session. Go to File>Recover>previous session or File>Recover>Autosave, then choose a file that was autosaved before disaster struck.

Comment: Auto-saves will not retain this information either, I am afraid. If whatever value is keyframed and then changed but not keyframed again, only the keyframed value will be saved at that frame...

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys indeed, all actions that are not keyframed never existed in the first place. But the user can at least go back to before erasing the keyframes.

Comment: Thanks all. Yes, without keyframing the autosave didn't work. However, because I had mirrored objects and centered their local CS on the global CS, I was able to remove the odd transforms Blender put on my non-keyed objects by using ALT + R and ALT+G. I think this only would work in very specific cases though, depending on the locations and pivot points of the objects.